# Replace dynamic token in Ant

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I have an ant file which iterates over a list of values retrieved from a configuration file and, for each one, does some other tasks. What I want is, also for every one of these values, replace a token for another value. Something like this:

My configuration file is

```
list=AAA,BBB,CCC
```

Then my ant file would be something like this

```
...
<property name="tokenList" location="${list}" />
...
<for list="${tokenList}" param="tkn">
  <sequential>
     do_some_other_tasks
     <replace file="myFile.txt" token="@{tkn}.vrsn" value="1111"/>
  </sequential>
</for>
```

So, in myFile.txt for the first iteration over ${tokenList} it would replace 'AAA.vrsn' for '1111', in the second 'BBB.vrsn' and so on.

This is a simplified version of my problem, but as far as I can tell, token has to be a fixed String, as this is not working as it is.

Any idea on how to achieve this? 
Thanks

Comment: not really clear what you want to achieve, so i guess you want to replace first token with 1111, second with 2222, third with 3333 .. etc. ?

Comment: welll, in this example it would be all tokens with 1111, but this is just an example; the main thing for me is that it seems that token in <replace> has to be a fixed string, and I need to be dynamic.